# Shrine - Derivation Endpoint and full path URLs with Cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-cloudfront, shrine

I'm using Shrine with Rails to upload my images directly to S3, they are then served using Cloudfront.

My setup is working great, but I'm stuck trying to answer 2 issues:

1) User uploads a new Image via Uppy. They click "Create Image Page" which creates a new "page" object. The user is taken to a blank page, while the Image derivative is being created in a background process using Sidekiq. How can we have the image "pop-in" via JS once the derivative is successfully created and promoted to /store? Is there a callback we can pick up on, or is it possible to keep trying to find the derivative via JS until it exists?

2) Using the Derivatives Endpoint plugin, all of the image URLs are relative. Is there a way to serve this as absolute URLs from Cloudfront/Custom Domain? Here's an example using Rails:

Ruby code:

```
<%= image_tag(image.image_file.derivation_url(:banner, 800, 300)) %>
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<img src="/derivations/images/banner/800/300/...">
```

How can I instead serve this resulting URL:

```
<img src="http://abc123.cloudfront.net/derivations/images/banner/800/300/...">
```

Was this intentional to prevent DoS? Thanks.

Adding the host option to "derivation_endpoint" causes the following error returned as XML:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>...</RequestId>
    <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

Could this be my Cloudfront access settings? Maybe CORS.

Here is my derivation_endpoint setup in **image_uploader.rb**

```
plugin :derivation_endpoint, host: "http://abc123.cloudfront.net", prefix: "derivations", secret_key: ..., upload: true
```

**routes.rb**

```
mount Shrine.presign_endpoint(:cache) => "s3/params"
mount PhotoUploader.derivation_endpoint => "derivations/images"
```

**config/initializers/Shrine.rb**

```
Shrine.plugin :url_options, store: { host: "http://abc123.cloudfront.net" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since the background job will update the record with derivatives, the easiest would be to poll the "show" route of the record (i.e. `GET /images/:id`) on the client side. In this case the route could have an alternative JSON response via `respond_to`.

   Alternatively, you could send a message from the background job to the client once processing is finished, via WebSockets or something like [message_bus](https://github.com/SamSaffron/message_bus).
2. You can configure the `:host` option for the derivation_endpoint plugin:

   ```
   Shrine.plugin :derivation_endpoint, host: "https://cloudfront.net"
   ```

Comment: thanks Janko, that makes sense - in the show page I'll poll for the image until it exists, and then show it. For 2) I currently have derivation_endpoint running but adding the host option (for the same CloudFront config as my working derivatives) and am getting an "Access Denied" error. I have added my plugin config to my original question.

Comment: What is the response body of the "Access Denied" error? Is it coming from the derivation endpoint or CloudFront? Could you also include the derivation endpoint mounting code from your `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: I have edited and added these to my original question - I think the error is coming from CloudFront, so it could very well be my access settings. Have also added my routes.rb mounts.

Comment: just tested using an alternate CloudFront distribution, and it gave me the error "Missing Signature Param". Not sure if that's relevant, but still can't seem to access any images using the host option.

Comment: One other point - the CloudFront distribution I'm using the as "host" for my Derivation Endpoint is the same as I'm using as the `plugin :url_options, store: { host: "http://abc123.cloudfront.net" }` for the rest of my Shrine setup. Do they need to be different distributions?

Comment: They don't need to be different, as long as the CDN is used for the same host (your app). It seems that CloudFront is not passing the `signature` query parameter to the derivation endpoint, which is needed for DoS protection. You'll need to configure CloudFront to pass this query parameter.

Comment: is there a guide to configure CloudFront to accept signatures? I can only find docs on how to generate the signatures. Before I get too carried away, is this the default planned use-case of Derivation Endpoints? With a CDN host, or should they ideally have the "host" set as the environment root_url?

Comment: There must be articles about it. You just need to search for how to make CloudFront pass selected query parameters. Yes, that's the default planned use-case.

Comment: Got it working, was missing an "origin" param from my Cloudfront setup. Thanks for the help Janko!

Comment: @kobius Could you share how you solved the CDN 403 issue? I have origin set successfully but still see the same issue. Shouldn't we expect `upload: true` to upload the image to S3  bucket used in CloudFront?